# Jasmine test angular component with private property

Tags: angular, jasmine, components

I have this code. I save `myData` in `ngOnInit`. When I test for myMethod on the click of a button this.myData is `undefined` in myMethod.

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: ''
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   myData: MyClass;
   constructor() {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.myData = // some code
   }

   myMethod() {
    this.myData is undefined here
   }
}
```

My spec file is:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

 // set up stubs 
 beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [  MyComponent ],
  providers:    [
  ],
  imports: [
   FormContainer
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
.compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
 }));

  it('should call myMethod', fakeAsync(() => {
    element.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(async() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: Do you have `myData` set as MyClass property?

Comment: @codeepic Yeah I have I have updated the question, the program compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are querying for the button before it exists.  Simply move your `fixture.detectChanges()` to before your `element.querySelectorAll()` and it should work.  See [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing) for details as to why.

```
it('should call myMethod', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(comp, 'myMethod').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <--- Move to here from below ...
    element.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click();
    // fixture.detectChanges();  <-- Move this ...
    expect(comp.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // fixture.whenStable().then(async(() => {
    //   fixture.detectChanges();
    // }));
}));
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54317647?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts).  Check out the console, as I modified `myMethod()` as follows:

```
myMethod() {
  console.log(this.myData); // is no longer undefined here
}
```

I hope this helps.

## Update

I have modified the StackBlitz to make this more clear.  Here are the new tests in the StackBlitz:

```
it('comp.myData should be undefined if element.query is first', () => {
    element.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click();
    expect(comp.myData).toBeUndefined(); // <-- Note this is UNDEFINED at this point
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <--- This is in the wrong place ...
});

it('comp.myData should be defined if fixture.detectChanges() is first', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <--- Now this is in the before the query.
    element.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click();
    expect(comp.myData).toEqual({data: 'test'}); // <-- Note this is now defined
});
```

If you check out the console.log you will see the following:

```
Console was cleared
undefined

{data: "test"}
```

The first undefined is from the first test, when `fixture.detectChanges()` is in the wrong spot.  The second `{data: "test"}` is from the second test where it is now defined.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I moved it below, and it still works : https://stackoverflow-q-54317647-yfuuga.stackblitz.io

Comment: The test still passes, yes (I probably should have been more clear about that) - but in the console.log() you will see that `this.myData` is `undefined` if the `fixture.detectChanges()` is after the `element.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: I still see {data: "test"} in the console : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54317647-ocxugf?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts

Comment: Actually if you open the console in the link you sent in the previous comment, you will see it says "undefined".  Anyway, I have updated my answer above to hopefully make this crystal clear. :)

Comment: It works now, didn't realize I've to work test  and not click on the button.

Comment: I’m glad you got it sorted.  :)